# Empty range executes as Not Nothing

Tags: vba

This sub compares old data (Sheet3) with new (Sheet1). New data can appear anywhere in the range, but there are never empty rows in between. My code calls sndPlaySound32 every time I execute, even when there is no new data. Why? Is a range always something if it's set using xldirections?

```
    Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 _
    Lib "winmm.dll" _
    Alias "sndPlaySoundA" ( _
    ByVal lpszSoundName As String, _
    ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long 


    Sub CheckNew()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim rngInput As Range
    Dim wksInput As Worksheet
    Dim VarSheet1 As Variant
    Dim VarSheet2 As Variant

    Set wksInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    VarSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
    VarSheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C1:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)


        For I = 1 To UBound(VarSheet2, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(VarSheet1, 1)
                If VarSheet1(I, 1) = VarSheet2(j, 1) Then
                wksInput.Rows(I).EntireRow.ClearContents
                Else
                'New data
                End If
           Next j
        Next I
        If Not rngInput Is Nothing Then
        sndPlaySound32 "C:\Windows\Media\Ring03.wav", &H0
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not rngInput Is Nothing Then` doesn't check whether range has no data, but check whether `rngInput` _refers_ to `Range` object. You can use something like this: `If Application.Counta(rngInput) Then`

Comment: You're right! Thanks. If you put it up as an answer I'll checkmark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments,

```
If Not rngInput Is Nothing Then
```

doesn't check whether range has no data, but check whether `rngInput` *refers* to `Range` object.

You can use this one instead:

```
If Application.CountA(rngInput) Then
   sndPlaySound32 "C:\Windows\Media\Ring03.wav", &H0
End If
```

or more reliable:

```
If Not rngInput Is Nothing Then
   If Application.CountA(rngInput) Then
      sndPlaySound32 "C:\Windows\Media\Ring03.wav", &H0
   End If
End If
```